# Pass value from repository to CrudController in Symfony

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I want to pass value to the choice field, so I will get a nice list of available options. I've tried doing it this way:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName, KlientRepository $repository): iterable

    {
        $wszyscy_klienci = strval(json_encode($repository->listaKlientow()));
        return [
    
            TextField::new('nazwa'),
            ChoiceField::new('klient')->setChoices($wszyscy_klienci),
            //AssociationField::new('NazwiskoKlienta', 'Klient')->autocomplete(),
            TextField::new('typ'),
            TextField::new('adres'),
            DateField::new('deadline'),
        ];
    }
```

But it returns me a Error that AbstractCrudController is not compatibile with "KlientRepository $repository" which I have put in the function. How I can make it work? I tried using AssociationField instead, but EasyAdmin docs are empty.

Symfony 5.4, EasyAdmin 4

EDIT***

It is possible by doing this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        $Krepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Klient::class);
        $w_klienci = array_values(array_column($Krepository->listaKlientow(), 'firma'));
        $w_klienci_keys = array_combine($w_klienci, $w_klienci);

        return [
            TextField::new('nazwa'),
            ChoiceField::new('klient')->setChoices($w_klienci_keys),
            TextField::new('typ'),
            TextField::new('adres'),
            DateField::new('deadline'),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `configureFields` doesnt take any extra properties, remove that then check this part of the documentation for an [AssosiationField](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/AssociationField.html) right at the bottom of the doc you can use your repository..

Comment: Thank you! They have added the documentation for that field in the recent days, as it was not present a few days ago.

Comment: You're correct, just checked the repo on Github and they were updated 21 hours ago. They must have read your mind that you needed them :)

Comment: I've tried using the AssociationField, but it didn't want to work as I expected so I somehow managed to do it with ChoiceField :-)) I've posted the code in my question.